# How to randomly select a fixed number of files in the current directory in windows explorer using a shortcut key in AutoHotKey program

Tags: autohotkey

how to randomly select a fixed number of files in the current directory in windows explorer using a shortcut key in AutoHotKey program

for example:

```
Shift + Control + 1     to select 1  random file
Shift + Control + 2     to select 25 random file
Shift + Control + 3     to select 35 random file
Shift + Control + 4     to select 40 random file
Shift + Control + 7     to select 70 random file
```

I appreciate your help, and sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a site for coding requests. Please post your code and explain specifically where you have problems implementing the solution.